# Newbie needs help with hyphen confusion!

Tags: grammar

I'm new here, trying to sharpen up my grammar skills due to a new transcription job.
I have a question pertaining to one of the documents I'm typing right now. I use the Grammarly app as my word editor and it's suggesting that I write "post-C-section" instead of "post C-section". I researched it and it seems to make sense to add the hyphen, but I can't get over how incorrect it looks. Opinions?

Comment: See this question on our sister site ELU: [Use of hyphen with the prefix "post-"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/357436/191178)

Answer (score 1):

It depends; if the "post C-section" is being used as an adjective. For example: state of the art:

> State-of-the-art technology

The "state of the art" is hyphenated as it is used as an adjective describing the technology, as in the technology is the best in it's field, or "art." If its going to be something like:

> Post-C-section recovery

Or

> Post-C-section side effects

Multi-word phrases are only hyphenated when they are being used as an adjective to describe another word.